# Making a surface reflective / mirror like in Java 3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I've been trying to make a surface in Java 3D reflect in a similar manner to a mirror. The API says to use TexCoordGeneration in SPHERE_MAP mode, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference at all. 
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
Appearance reflectAp = new Appearance();
TexCoordGeneration tex = new TexCoordGeneration();
tex.setGenMode(TexCoordGeneration.SPHERE_MAP);

reflectAp.setMaterial(matFact.silver());
reflectAp.setTexCoordGeneration(tex);

flat = new Box(.7f, .9f, .01f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS | Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, reflectAp);
```

Comment: It may not be what you are looking for but here. [ClICKY CLICKY](https://www.java.net//node/662713)
However if its not what you are looking for try contacting. [Necrowizzard](http://www.minecraftdl.com/developers/necrowizzard/)